# Mostrar y ocultar botón con link dependiendo de una condición

Tags: css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<Style>

body {
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif!important;
}

.google-visualization-table-table {
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif!important;
}

.photo {
width:50px;
height: 50px;
float:left;
margin:5px 10px 5px 5px!important;
}

.photo-container {
 border-radius: 300px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
margin: 0 auto;
border: solid 4px white;
margin:0 auto!important;
}

.name {
color:#4E423B;
margin-top:20px!important;
}

.about-container {
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
width:100%;
padding: 30px 10px;
text-align: center;
}

.about-name {
margin-bottom: 0px!important;
font-weight: initial;
color: #4E423B;
}

.department {
margin-top: 0px!important;
color: #009CE0;
font-weight:bold;
}

.color {
margin-top: 0px!important;
color: #C0392B;
font-weight:bold;
}

.info-container {
text-align: left;
border-top: 1px solid #f8f8f8;
}

.info-boton {
text-align: right;
border-top: 1px solid #f8f8f8;
}

.basic-info-container{
padding: 4%;
vertical-align: top;
}

table {
border: 1px solid #dddddd;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #fff;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
 background-color: #dddddd;
}

a:link, a:visited {
  background-color: #009CE0;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover, a:active {
  background-color: #1B4F72;
}

#sidebar {
display:flex;
}

</Style>


<div class="about-container">
<div class="photo-container">
<img src="{{Picture}}" width="100%">
</div>
<p class="about-name"><b>{{Empresa}}</b><br>{{Fecha Incidente}}</br>
</p>
<p class="department">{{Clasificación}}</p>
<div class="info-container">
<div class="color">
<h3><b>Información</b></h3></div>
<b>Trabajador Involucrado</b>: {{Nombre Trabajador}} <br>
<b>Cargo</b>: {{Cargo}}<br>
<b>Lugar del Accidente</b>: {{Lugar del Accidente}}<br>
<b>Tipo de Lesión</b>: {{Tipo de lesión}}</br>
<b>Parte del Cuerpo</b>: {{Parte del Cuerpo}}</br>
<b>Fecha de Alta</b>: {{Fecha Alta}}</br>
<b>Días Perdidos</b>: {{Dias Perdidos}}</br></p>
<div class="color">
<h3><b>Descripción</b></h3></div>
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>

<td>{{Descripción}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<br></br>

<div class="department">
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
<td><h3><b>{{Estatus}}</h3> <h2>{{Cumplimiento}}</b></h2>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div class="info-container">
<div class="color">
<h3><b>Respaldos Documentales</b></h3></div>


<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
<td><b>Informe Flash</b></td>
<td>
<h5><p class="department">{{C1}}</p></td></h5>
<td><a href="{{Informe Flash}}" target="_blank">Ver</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Informe Investigación</b></td>
<td>
<h5><p class="department">{{C2}}</p></td></h5>
<td><a href="{{Informe Investigación}}" target="_blank">Ver</a></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Declaraciones</b></td>
<td>
<h5><p class="department">{{C3}}</td></p></h5>
<td><a href="{{Declaraciones}}" target="_blank">Ver</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Documentación de Investigación</b></td>
<td>
<h5><p class="department">{{C4}}</td></p></h5>
<td><a href="{{Documentación de Investigación}}" target="_blank">Ver</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Atención Policlínico</b></td>
<td>
<h5><p class="department">{{C5}}</td></p></h5>
<td><a href="{{Atención Policlínico}}" target="_blank">Ver</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>DIAT</b></td>
<td>
<h5><p class="department">{{C6}}</td></p></h5>
<td><a href="{{DIAT}}" target="_blank">Ver</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>RECA</b></td>
<td>
<h5><p class="department">{{C7}}</td></p></h5>
<td><a href="{{RECA}}" target="_blank">Ver</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Certificado Atención y Reposo</b></td>
<td>
<h5><p class="department">{{C8}}</td></p></h5>
<td><a href="{{Certificado Atención y Reposo}}" target="_blank">Ver</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Certificado de Alta</b></td>
<td>
<h5><p class="department">{{C9}}</td></p></h5>
<td><a href="{{Certificado de Alta}}" target="_blank">Ver</a></td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>
</div>
```

Soy principiante en esto de la programación, pero estoy programando en `html` y `css` con un intermediario para manejo de tablas interactivas (awesome table), con almacenamiento de datos, el cual programo en una hoja de calculo de google, y se hace la interfaz con awesome table, el cual me lo diseña.

Pero mi pregunta va por el lado de que en hay una tabla de 3 columnas (ver apartado respaldo documentales). En la primera columna me muestra los documentos que deben ser cargados al sistema, en la segunda columna me dice el estado si: **Documento Disponible, Sin Documento o No Aplica** y en la tercera columna hay un botón el cual al hacer click me muestra el documento adjunto.

Entonces no se como hacerlo para que cuando en la segunda columna me diga **Documento Disponible** me aparezca el botón automáticamente en la tercera columna, y si me dice **Sin Documento** o **No Aplica**, no me muestre el botón.

Dejo el código, lo trate de adaptar para que lo vean ya que en hoja de calculo google se programa aparte el **about** y **style**. no se verá la información ya que esta vinculado a la hoja de calculo, lo que esta entre dos corchetes {{}}, se supone que aparecen los datos de acuerdo a la organización seleccionada según la base de datos de la hoja de calculo.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor trata de redactar con espacios y saltos de renglón, pues hacer una lectura así se hace difícil

Comment: Yo usaría Jquery para conseguir lo que buscas pero nose si te sirve.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que alcanzo a entender, necesitas un condicional... por ejemplo, `if(estado = 'Disponible'){mostrar botón};`, esto lo puedes lograr con `jQuery`.

```js
//Cuando cargue el documento
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Ejecuto la función por cada fila
  $('table tbody tr').each(function(i, row) {
      //Obtengo el estado
      var estado = $(row).find('.estado').html();
      console.log(estado)
      //Valido si el estado es igual a disponible
      if(estado == 'Disponible'){
        //Elimino el atributo hidden del botón
        $(row).find('button').removeAttr('hidden');
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Documento</th>
    <th>Estado</th>
    <th>Adjuntos</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>102835465</td>
    <td class="estado">Disponible</td>
    <td><button hidden>ver documento</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>159684257</td>
    <td class="estado">Sin Documento</td>
    <td><button hidden>ver documento</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>15598462</td>
    <td class="estado">No Aplica</td>
    <td><button hidden>ver documento</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>106584975</td>
    <td class="estado">Disponible</td>
    <td><button hidden>ver documento</button></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Te dejo un link a la documentación oficial https://api.jquery.com/. Haz pruebas y regresa aquí si tienes dudas puntuales, ya que tu pregunta, tal y como está formulada, es considerada demasiado amplia.

**Edición:**

Con etiquetas `<a>` funciona de manera muy similar, solo des saber donde aplicar las reglas.

Respecto a tu otra duda, no he trabajado con `awesome table` pero lo que tu necesitas es controlar lo que se muestra en el DOM y esta función se ejecuta después de cargado `$(document).ready(function() {}`

Asegúrate de agregar la dependencia de `jQuery` en el `head` de tu estructura `html`... justo como en el ejemplo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

**Tomé parte de tu código para darte un ejemplo con etiquetas `<a>`**

```js
//Cuando cargue el documento
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Ejecuto la función por cada fila
  $('table tbody tr').each(function(i, row) {
      //Obtengo el estado
      var estado = $(row).find('.estado').html();
      //Valido si el estado es diferente a disponible
      if(estado != 'Disponible'){
        //Agrego la regla css display: none;
        $(row).find('.link').css('display', 'none');
      }
  });
});
```

```css
a:link, a:visited {
  background-color: #009CE0;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover, a:active {
  background-color: #1B4F72;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Documento</th>
    <th>Estado</th>
    <th>Adjuntos</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>102835465</td>
    <td class="estado">Disponible</td>
    <td><a class="link" href="{{Informe Flash}}" target="_blank">Ver</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>159684257</td>
    <td class="estado">Sin Documento</td>
    <td><a class="link" href="{{Informe Investigación}}" target="_blank">Ver</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>15598462</td>
    <td class="estado">No Aplica</td>
    <td><a class="link" href="{{Declaraciones}}" target="_blank">Ver</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>106584975</td>
    <td class="estado">Disponible</td>
    <td><a class="link" href="{{Documentación de Investigación}}" target="_blank">Ver</a></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edición 2:**

Finalmente, te dejo el mismo ejemplo pero con `JavaScript` puro. *Nótese que eliminé la dependencia de `jQuery`*

```js
//obtengo la cantidad de filas que contiena la tabla
var filas = document.getElementById("tabla").rows.length;
//declaro el ciclo que recorrerá cada tabla
//(filas -1 es para omitir la fila de los encabezados)
for (i=0; i<filas-1; i++){
  //obtengo el estado
  var estado = document.getElementsByClassName('estado')[i].innerText;
  //valido si el estado es diferente a Disponible
  if(estado != 'Disponible'){
    //agrego el estilo para ocultar el botón
    document.getElementsByClassName('link')[i].style.display="none";
  }
}
```

```css
a:link, a:visited {
  background-color: #009CE0;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover, a:active {
  background-color: #1B4F72;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <table id="tabla">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Documento</th>
    <th>Estado</th>
    <th>Adjuntos</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>102835465</td>
    <td class="estado">Disponible</td>
    <td><a class="link" href="{{Informe Flash}}" target="_blank">Ver</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>159684257</td>
    <td class="estado">Sin Documento</td>
    <td><a class="link" href="{{Informe Investigación}}" target="_blank">Ver</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>15598462</td>
    <td class="estado">No Aplica</td>
    <td><a class="link" href="{{Declaraciones}}" target="_blank">Ver</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>106584975</td>
    <td class="estado">Disponible</td>
    <td><a class="link" href="{{Documentación de Investigación}}" target="_blank">Ver</a></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Estimado primero que nada agradecer su respuesta, lo intente hacer como ud me dice, pero resulta que el intermediario que uso para que me diceñe la tabla que es awesome table, no soporta codigos Script, solo hatml y CSS. Pero la idea que ud me planteo me sirve, solo es que en el codigo que le adjunte mas arriba lo de los botones lo hago con un codigo directo que lo declaro con la letra "a" en el style. favor agradecere su respuesta si se puede lograr lo que quiero solo con html y CSS.

Comment: Edité mi respuesta para agregar un ejemplo usando parte de tu código y **mostrándote como debes agregar la dependencia de `jQuery`**. Por lo que leí en la documentación del plugin, está construido con `javascript`. Por ende, es posible que si tenga soporte aunque sea complejo. Prueba con esta solución, o en caso contrario, debemos tratar de hacerlo con `javascript` puro _Sin hacer uso de `jQuery`_

Comment: Estimado nuevamente gracias por su tiempo, el código que me facilito esta perfecto es justo lo que necesito, pero con la forma que estoy programando que es por medio de awesome table se me complica un poco el asunto. Edité mi pregunta donde adjunto una fotografía de como se programa por medio de google sheets (hoja de calculo google) donde en las columnas se pone <style>, <script>, pero tengo problemas de donde insertar la parte del llamado de la biblioteca de jquery (<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>) es lo único que me falta.

Comment: Prueba agregándolo en la columna **F**, justo después de cerrar `<link "https://...">`

Comment: Prueba y si no funciona, comenta y dame tiempo para maquetar el script en `JavaScript` puro

Comment: No funciona donde me dices....te agradezco mucho, ojala puedas maquetar el script en JavaScrit. muchas gracias

Comment: Listo. Agregué el último ejemplo con `JavaScript` puro. Espero que esta vez si te funcione.